# string to date time format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, datetime

I have `mysql` db and I want to get the record of daily complete transactions.

Transactions which get complete successfully get a trans date time in format like `20160816114733,1.`

Now I want to convert this string to valid date time format i.e `(2016-08-16 11:47:33)` in mysql and get the daily transactions from this value.

Comment: do you need format 20160816114733 to 2016-08-16 11:47:33 in mysql or in php?

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(20160816114733,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

**OR** you can try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(20160816114733,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
```

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.